# Big O for my binary search algorithm with for loop?

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity, binary-search

I am trying to get my algorithm down to the lowest possible running time.

What is the running time of this algorithm; is it O(log n) or O(n log n) because of the for loop?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class countDifferenceBetweenTwoArrays {
  private static int countDifference(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
    int differenceCount = 0;
    for (Integer i : arrayA) {
      if (Arrays.binarySearch(arrayB, i) < 0) {
        differenceCount++;
      }
    }
    for (Integer i : arrayA) {
      if (Arrays.binarySearch(arrayB, i) < 0) {
        differenceCount++;
      }
    }
    return differenceCount;
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix `int` and `Integer` if you don't need to. Use `for (int i : arrayA)` instead, otherwise java needs to autobox the `int` for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is O(nlog(n)). You iterate over each array, an operation that is O(n). In each iteration, you perform an O(log(n)) binary search operation. This gives you an O(nlog(n)) running time for processing each array. You do this twice, but we ignore the constant factor of 2, leaving us with O(nlog(n)) for the entire function.

Comment: Is it possible to get it down to O(n) time?

Comment: Yes, if you make creative use of a hash table.

Comment: can you suggest any ideas?

Comment: Are you familiar with hashtables?

Comment: I'm okay with them, any ideas? :D

Comment: One thing you can do with hashtables is check to see if a particular key is in the hashtable or not.  This can be done in constant time (O(1)).  Imagine what would happen if you inserted each element in array B into a hashtable as a key (along with a dummy value).  What could you then do?

Comment: I could check whether the other array matches the values in the hashtable. But I'm not familiar with the method calls :(

Answer (score 1):

Hash table for checking collisions between integers.

returns the number of distinct integers in both arrays

```
  private static int distinctNumberOfItems(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {

    HashSet<Integer> setA = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> setB = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i : arrayA) {
      setA.add(i);
      setB.add(i);
    }

    for (int i : arrayB) {
      setB.add(i);
      if (setA.contains(i))
        setB.remove(i);
    }
    System.out.println(setB);
    return setB.size();
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have posted this is the answer section, but asked a question. If you are trying to ask another question, you may make a new post

Comment: It's nearly an answer, just that there's no getInt for HashSets

Comment: Technically, there isn't a getInt on booleans because that what you are calling that method on

Comment: @cricket_007 How may I implement similar logic?

Comment: I don't know what logic that is. Why do you need getInt? The j variable is the only int that you have access to in that loop. I think you mean `setA.contains(j)`

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think that's quite right.  If you want to see if an integer j is in HashSet setA, just do if (setA.contains( j )) ...  setA.contains(setB) is always going to return false, because it's testing if setB itself (the object) is a member of setA.  Since setA and setB are sets of Integers, you will have to check each individual element of arrayA is in setB, and vice versa.

Comment: @cricket_007 look at my new updated answer and see if it's correct, I can't see any problems with it

Comment: You may want to think about your logic a little bit.  If you replace setA.contains(setB).getInt() with setA.contains(j), then your program is semantically correct.  However, you will simply be populating setB with the elements that are in both arrays.  You will be calculating the size of the intersection instead of the size of the difference.

Comment: What if one array has 100 elements and the other has none? You return 0?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I completely bombed a phone interview for an internship a couple years back on this very question.

Comment: @cricket_007 take a look

Comment: I posted my own answer.

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think it'll work without a Hashset C. Also, it won't be O(log n) time, which is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Your current solution here returns 4, which is not correct

Comment: No, that's what I was looking for. Try printing out setC, it'll return 2, 3, 8, 9

Comment: I've optimised the solution to O(n) now using only 2 HashSets

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) between the sets to get the unique elements in each. In Java, this is done with [`Set#removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
private static int distinctNumberOfItems(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {

    HashSet<Integer> setA = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> setB = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> setC = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i : arrayA) {
        setA.add(i);
        setC.add(i);
    }
    for (int i : arrayB) {
        setB.add(i);
    }

    setA.removeAll(setB);
    setB.removeAll(setC);
    return setA.size() + setB.size();
}
```

Comment: You still need a copy HashSet C to copy all the distinct values from HashSet A and B. Then you need to perform your removeAll method. But then, there's still no performance improvement? It's still going to be O(n).

Comment: Is there a way to bring it down to O(log n) instead of O(n)?

Comment: You can't get O(logn) given that you need to at least loop over every element to see if it's in the other. However, O(n) is an improvement over your original code, which is O(nlogn).

Comment: btw, this won't work for arrays with duplicate elements. However, you could build up a histogram of counts (`Map<Integer, Integer>`) to still get O(n).

Comment: @CarolineRudolph Huh? You don't need a HashSet C... And O(n) is the lowest you can do to find all distinct elements because you have to iterate over the all the elements from **at least one** list.

Comment: @bcorso My answer works for arrays with duplicate elements since the HashSet only adds distinct elements

Comment: @cricket_007 your answer won't work because the answer is 4: 2, 8, 3 and 9.

Comment: @cricket_007, he's referring to the following:  What if you wanted to define diff(Array a, Array b) such that diff([0, 0, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2]) == [0, 3, 3].  I was asked this on an interview.

Comment: @CarolineRudolph - Oooh, you want **all** distinct elements. I see what you're saying

Comment: Exactly lol, thanks for your help though. You were really enlightening!

Comment: @cricket_007 guess it depends on what the actual question is. In the original question the function was `countDifferenceBetweenTwoArrays`, which I interpreted as, if `a=[0,1,1,2,3]` and `b=[3,2,1]`, then diff is `[0,1]`.

Comment: @CarolineRudolph Fixed it :D

Comment: @cricket_007 check mine ;D 2 HashSets - nanynanybooboo :P

Comment: @CarolineRudolph as long as you're learning something, that's all that matters